# Upgrading to spartacus 3.4 gives warnings of deprecated functions like "function" is deprecated: since 3.2

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Upgrading to spartacus 3.4 I get warnings of deprecated function like "function" is deprecated: since 3.2, use `UserProfileService.updateProfileCallState.clear()` from `@spartacus/user` package.  **I cant find the new function on UserProfileService**

Comment: Did you try message to vendor in first place? They should have upgrade instruction for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question, we've updated the deprecation note recently. Please take a look at the comments on the [file](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/release/3.4.x/projects/core/src/user/facade/user.service.ts).

It seems you are using `resetUpdatePersonalDetailsProcessingState()` this method is deprecated but will not be removed until Spartacus version 4.0, so you can keep using it until then. For context we are moving away from NgRX gradually and one of the places we are doing it first is in the user library.

Note that this method is no longer needed when you use `UserProfileFacade.update()`. As there is no more process state. You can see an example of it's usage [here](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/feature-libs/user/profile/components/update-profile/update-profile-component.service.ts#L48-L51).